# How do I perform a deletion of table entries from a full outer join?

Tags: oracle

**What I have is several tables...two of them being:**

```
CREATE TABLE Orders(
oid int NOT NULL,
rdate date,
sdate date,
cid int NOT NULL,
eid int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (oid),
FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES Customer(cid),
FOREIGN KEY (eid) REFERENCES Employee(eid));

CREATE TABLE PartOrder(
poid int NOT NULL,
pid int NOT NULL,
oid int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (poid),
FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES Part(pid),
FOREIGN KEY (oid) REFERENCES Orders(oid));
```

**What I need to do is this:**

> Create and execute a query that deletes all PartOrder records for Orders for which the shipping date is in the past.

**So, I came up with this...**

```
DELETE 
FROM (SELECT * FROM PartOrder FULL OUTER JOIN Orders ON partorder.oid=orders.oid)
WHERE sdate<sysdate;
```

**This is giving me this error:**

> ORA-01752: cannot delete from view without exactly one key-preserved table

Can someone offer me some insight?

Comment: I figured it out! Removed "FULL OUTER JOIN" and replaced with just "JOIN".

Comment: If the problem is solved, go ahead and post the solution you found as answer and accept it for the time being, you can always change the accepted answer later if a better solution comes along.

Comment: `full outer join` and `join` have different behavior.  Do you know why you were trying to use a `full outer join` in the first place?

Comment: @LeviJ - note that `JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` are synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write this as something like

```
DELETE FROM PARTORDER
  WHERE POID IN (SELECT p.POID
                   FROM PARTORDER p
                   INNER JOIN ORDERS o
                     ON o.OID = p.OID
                   WHERE o.SDATE < SYSDATE);
```

Best of luck.